# Interactive SVG in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, svg, breakpoints

I've designed and coded an interactive SVG that I've had to implement as HTML in WordPress because it only acts as a useless static image if it's entered as an SVG in an image block.
So far, that means that it's not responsive and loads at full size on a phone. I want people to see it in full, straight away, not zoom out to see it.
Is there another way to make it work without being an HTML dump? And even as code, how would I reduce it to fit screen sizes? Bearing in mind that my brain may implode if you suggest coding breakpoints or something like that.
I'm using a Blocksy child theme with no page builder.
The code itself works fine so there seems no point in me pasting a shortened version of the code. The page is here, if that helps.
Www.orderaround.co.uk

Comment: If the code is too long that's a sign that you need to create a [mcve] before asking the question.

Comment: I don't really see what difference it would make. The code works just fine, whether I chop it down or not. The issue is integration into WordPress.

Comment: How are you trying to implement this? You haven't told us *where* you are putting this SVG. Is this in a post/page WYSIWYG? Somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was clear about it. It can't be added as an image as the interactivity as pects don't work if you do. It's been added in an HTML block on the front static page. Because it's set as HTML, it's not Wysiwyg. It all works well, in terms of code. Whilst it's easy to set an image size in an image block, I don't know how to set the size for different screen sizes with having to have been added as HTML code. You'll see the problem if you load the page on a phone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Right, I've fixed it myself. All I needed to do was remove the width and height specifications from the beginning of the svg code. It now fits to whatever container it's being displayed in.